# Good practice: Giving height to parent container as well as its children

Tags: css, height, parent-child

Is it a good practice to give children of a container their individual heights even if the parent container already has a height property and if not is there any way of passing the parent containers height to some of  its children without using

```
    height: inherit;
```

I dont want to write individually to all children this property.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a css precompiler you can save the height of the container to a variable and then define it for the specific child container as its individual Height. Your Question is not very clear because you don't describe how your child-container are positioned in the parent container